# Wordpress same archive template for custom post type and taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy

I created a custom taxonomy for tags

```
function create_topics_nonhierarchical_taxonomy() {

  // Labels part for the GUI

  $labels = array(
    'name' => _x( 'Topics', 'taxonomy general name' ),
    'singular_name' => _x( 'Topic', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
    'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Topics' ),
    'popular_items' => __( 'Popular Topics' ),
    'all_items' => __( 'All Topics' ),
    'parent_item' => null,
    'parent_item_colon' => null,
    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Topic' ), 
    'update_item' => __( 'Update Topic' ),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Topic' ),
    'new_item_name' => __( 'New Topic Name' ),
    'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate topics with commas' ),
    'add_or_remove_items' => __( 'Add or remove topics' ),
    'choose_from_most_used' => __( 'Choose from the most used topics' ),
    'menu_name' => __( 'Topics' )
  ); 

  // Now register the non-hierarchical taxonomy like tag

  register_taxonomy('topics','post',array(
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'labels' => $labels,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
    'query_var' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'topic' ),
  ));
}
```

and connected it to my custom post type

```
register_post_type( 'video', array(
   ...
   'taxonomies' => array( 'topics' ),
   ...
) );
```

The custom post type uses `archive-video.php` as the archive template. Is it possible to use the same archive template for the custom taxonomy? Without duplicating the file and renaming it.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/make-archives-php-include-custom-post-types/

Comment: Thank you. The function will not work because I'm not using archives.php. I'm using a custom archive named archive-video.php (which is also in a subdirectory)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of the [`template_include`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include) filter to set the template you need for a specific condition

You can try something like this

```
add_filter( 'template_include', function ( $template ) {

    if ( is_tax( 'topics' ) ) {
    $new_template = locate_template( array( 'archive-video.php' ) );
        if ( '' != $new_template ) {
            return $new_template ;
        }
    }
    return $template;

}, PHP_INT_MAX, 2 );
```

Comment: There is an extra space after archive-video.php that breaks your example. I pulled out my hair for an hour over it but I can't edit it because the edit is less than 6 characters.

Comment: @StephenSmith Thanks for pointing that out, have corrected it :-)

Answer (score 4):

I'd create the taxonomy file and have it load the archive file. This avoids having two copies of the same file which need to be kept in sync. WooCommerce uses the same approach for product categories and tags.

Create `taxonomy-topics.php` and add the following code:

```
<?php

// Find and load the archive template.
locate_template( 'archive-video.php', true );
```